# How can we prevent the serialization of fields of a sub type of a type parameter in jackson/json?

Tags: java, json, inheritance, jackson, type-parameter

The second junit test serializes an instance of a class which has a type parameter. The instance is of type `ParametricType<SubType>`. The serializer was initialized by using `constructParametricType(ParametricType.class, SuperType.class)` as type information. We can see that we initialized the serializer with the super type `SuperType` for the type parameter. We would now expect to get serialized json, containing only fields of the super type. But the field `B` of the sub type is also included.

It works in the first example where we do not wrap our `SuperType` in `ParametricType`.

So what are we missing in order to get only the super type fields as serialized output when we use a parametric type?

```
public static class SuperType {
    public int A;
}

public static class SubType extends SuperType {
    public int B;
}

public static class ParametricType<T> {
    public T Value;
}

@Test
public void doNotSerializeSubClassFieldsTest() throws Exception {
    var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    var writer = mapper.writerFor(SuperType.class);

    var subType = new SubType();
    subType.A = 1;
    subType.B = 2;

    var expectedValue = "{\"A\":1}";
    var data = writer.writeValueAsString(subType);

    assertEquals(expectedValue, data);
}

@Test
public void serializeNotSubclassAuthenticatedMessageTest() throws Exception {
    var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    var javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(ParametricType.class, SuperType.class);
    var writer = mapper.writerFor(javaType);

    var subType = new SubType();
    subType.A = 1;
    subType.B = 2;
    var parametricType = new ParametricType<>();
    parametricType.Value = subType;

    var expectedValue = "{\"Value\":{\"A\":1}}";
    var data = writer.writeValueAsString(parametricType);

    // it is actually "{\"Value\":{\"A\":1,\"B\":2}}"
    assertEquals(expectedValue, data);
}
```